# How to Load Obj file with its respective material

Tags: three.js

I am trying to load object with its material that I designated when I create the obj file. So far when I load the object, I only receive a black object. However, I wish to create a way to load the objects with its respective materials. Is there a way to do it?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use THREE.OBJMTLLoader.

See this for example:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl.html